# Remove user from folder permission using MS Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

We have a C# application that is using the Microsoft Graph API to display the contents of SharePoint folder to users in a Syncfusion FileManager control.  We need to grant permissions to those folders for certain users in order that they can collaborate on files.
We can add specific users using the sharing invitation to add a permission (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).  We also need to be able to remove a user from this permission without deleting the whole link (and therefore any other users using it).  I cannot see a way of doing this!

I have also tried using CreateLink (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) but get an ‘Invalid Request’ error when trying to ‘Grant’ permission to a user and therefore never get as far as trying to remove an individual user!.  The code I am using to try and 'Grant' permission is as follows (the last line produces the error):

```
public object CreateSharingLink(string itemId, List<string> recipientList, List<string> roles)
{
    if (itemId == null) return null;

    var type = "edit";
    var scope = "organization";

    Permission p = GraphClient.Drives[documentLibrary.Id].Items[itemId].CreateLink(type, scope).Request().PostAsync().Result;

    return GrantAccessToSharingLink(p.Link.WebUrl, recipientList, roles);
}

public object GrantAccessToSharingLink(string sharingUrl, List<string> recipientList, List<string> roles)
{
    List<DriveRecipient> recipients = (recipientList.Select(r => new DriveRecipient { Email = r })).ToList();
       
    string base64Value = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sharingUrl));
    string encodedUrl = "u!" + base64Value.TrimEnd('=').Replace('/', '_').Replace('+', '-');

    return GraphClient.Shares[encodedUrl].Permission.Grant(roles, recipients).Request().PostAsync().Result;
}
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

A similar question was asked a while ago but without an answer. [Remove GrantedTo user from Permission using Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078181/remove-grantedto-user-from-permission-using-graph-api/64895676#64895676)

Comment: You can delete only not inherited permissions. Only sharing permissions that are not inherited can be deleted. Here's the related doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/permission-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete only not inherited permissions. Only sharing permissions that are not inherited can be deleted. Here's the related [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/permission-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: This does not solve the issue. This will remove the entire permission, which the share link is attached to and thus remove all access to the share link for all users.